# Can't dismiss dialog

Tags: flutter

I'm using `SimpleDialog` which has children `SimpleDialogOption`that can be uses to build a list in the dialog. My dialog is in a `FutureBuilder` so I need to wrap the dialog with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)` . `SimpleDialogOption` has an `onPressed` callback where I can set the state. And this calls another rebuild which leaves the dialog open because of `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)` (I think!). If I don't call setState the dialog dismisses.  I'm unable to dismiss my dialog. Anyway around this...

```
FutureBuilder<List<Suburb>>(
            future: suburbs,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {

                // when future has not finished
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();

                // when future has finished
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  final suburbs = snapshot.data;
                  if (suburbs == null) {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      showAlertDialog(
                        context: context,
                        title: 'No postocde',
                        content: 'We can' '/t seem to find that postocode ',
                        defaultActionText: 'OK',
                      ).then((_) => _controller.clear());
                    });
                    return Container();
                  }
                  if (suburbs.length == 1) {

                  suburb = suburbs[0].name;
                        suburbCode = suburbs[0].code;
                   return(Text(suburbs[0].name));

                  } else if (suburbs.length == 2) {

                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return SimpleDialog(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              title: Text('Pick'),
                              children: [
                                SimpleDialogOption(
                                  child: Text(suburbs[0].name),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    setState(() {
                                      WidgetsBinding.instance
                                          .cancelFrameCallbackWithId(1);
                                      suburb = suburbs[0].name;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                SimpleDialogOption(
                                  child: Text(suburbs[1].name),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    setState(() {
                                      suburb = suburbs[0].name;
                                    });
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                          });


                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text(suburbs[0].name),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              suburb = suburbs[0].name;
                              suburbCode = suburbs[0].code;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text(suburbs[1].name),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              suburb = suburbs[1].name;
                              suburbCode = suburbs[1].code;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();

                // initial title
                default:
                  return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: If I don't, I get ` setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

Comment: I'm making an API call(with future builder). If I get two items back(snapshot.data==2) I need to present the options to the user so He can select one and I can setstate.

Comment: Maybe not a good option. I also have an alert dialog if the list is empty which works fine. I though I could do the same with Simple dialog but calling setstate keeps the dialog open.

Comment: SimpleDialog works as well without the `setState` in the callbacks

Comment: Could you please provide a description of the interaction you are trying to achieve? I find it very strange that you need to use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`. So please, if you can, explain the user experience you expect.

Comment: I'm using a future to return a list. The list can be null, 1 item or 2 items. If null user gets a dialog 'no suburb found'. If 1 item a Text widget displaying the text. And if 2 items, user has to choose from a Simple Dialog. .. I'll post the FB

Comment: show Dialog returns a future..that's why I'm calling `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`

Comment: hi, thanks a million...but I can't seem to get it working. So , no I can't seem to adapt it..

Comment: I'just want to grab the text for the list and use it .. but the the setstate prevents the dialog from dismissing.

Comment: that's fantastic @pskink cheers Bud.

Comment: Grrr, back to the same problem. .How the page works....On navigating to the screen I have a edittextfield.. The data entered is used as a param for the api call which returns the list. And the list is handled the way you perfectly described in the paste. It's nice when you can call the future in initState but I obviously can't in this use case..I think!

Comment: I can't seem to decouple the calls. My FB is in a state of waiting which I don't want to trigger until `onSumit` is called . Here is a poor attempt https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/j5rX4H5cSh/

Comment: updated with another paste. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yjnGQxtf96/

Comment: @pskink thanks so much for that. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bVD9sPTBQw/